# Profile specific application properties not picked by Spring Boot 3 native executable

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am planning to use a native image with Spring Boot 3. My environment-specific properties are stored in the application.properties file. Sample file

```
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
server.port=9092
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=local
server.port=9093
```

I build the native executable using the following command

```
./mvnw -Pnative native:compile -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

and run the executable using the below command

```
./target/<app-executable> -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

In the logs I see

```
No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
```

Am I doing something wrong or Are profiles not supported with Spring Boot 3 native image?

Comment: Try passing `server.port`, also I'm not certain if embedded profiles are supported in property files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to make it work by passing the arguments as -- instead of using -D.

For building the native image, no need to pass -D.

```
./mvnw -Pnative native:compile
```

And to run the executable with system properties, use the below command

```
./target/<app-executable> --spring.profiles.active=local
```

This picked up the server.port=9093.

Comment: ENV var also works: `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local ./target/<app-executable>`.